# Android: Return a string from a view?

Tags: android, view, onclick, android-intent

How do I get a string from a view? To be more specific I have 36 buttons in a tabview. When I click the button it calls an

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

from my XML to call the method `onClick(View v)`. I then want to pass variables via an intent to another activity based on the button clicked. Now I know my View of the button pressed is 'v', what I want to know is how to take that view and make it a string that I can manipulate.

Comment: Are you saying you want to pass information about the pressed button to another activity? I don't really understand what you mean by converting a View into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xml define of Button, set tag for it:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:text="Btn 1"
    android:tag="1"android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

And in `onClick` function:
public void onClick(View v)

```
{
    Button button = (Button) v;
    String tag = button.getTag.toString();
    //now open new Activity with this tag
    Intent intent = new Itent();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("tag", tag);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Boom! That's what I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this? It's **explicit class casting**, a Java language feature.

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    Button button = (Button) v;
    String info = button.getText();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    .....
}
```

Comment: This would have been what I selected but my buttons are imageButtons so I had to use the tag. Thanks for the help though!