# To get a String of Object tag

Tags: android, object, tags, switch-statement

I have a doubt related with tag. For example, if i have a button with a tag "ButtonTag". Tag is a object, but i would like to catch a string "ButtonTag" and use inside a switch. Summing up, to get a String of Object tag and to use in a Switch. Is possible ?

```
public void ArtGeneralButton(View view){
         selsub = view.getId();
         tagsub = view.getTag(); \\ Object -> String How???
        // String myString = getString(null,tagsub,);
         UpdateAnsList myUpdate = new UpdateAnsList(this);      
         myUpdate.StartUpdateAnsList(selsub,tagsub);

    }
```

Comment: What about `view.getTag().toString()`?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein : Does the `java.lang.String` class override the `toString()` method in order to return a `String` instance representing the data? Normally calling `toString()` on an `Object` simply returns a human-readable representation of the object reference.

Comment: @Squonk Well, you're right. Anyway, it seems to work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5672445/2649012

Comment: @FrankN.Stein : Yep, I had a feeling that `String` overrides the `toString()` method but I couldn't find the source code. Your suggestion is obviously also a valid answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String tagString = (String) view.getTag();
```

It's as simple as that as long as whatever was originally used to set the tag was a `String`

As for using a `String` in a `switch` is concerned, I prefer to use `int` as the key for a `switch`. In this case I'd set the tags as `ints` - either arbitrary values such as 1, 2, 3 etc or use the resource ids of strings in the `strings.xml` file.